# Cannot type in textarea after requesting with ajax

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing an ajax request and the output of this request is a textarea that is injected into a div. But for some reason I can't type in it in firefox. In google chrome I can't do ctrl-A.

I tried removing all of the css classes, but it still has weird behaviour.

Jquery:

```
$.get(settingsUrl, {}, function(response) {

  $(".action-remove").hide();

  container.addClass("editing-settings");

  var settingsPage = $(response).find("#settings").hide();

  container.html(settingsPage);

}
```

injected html:

```
<h2>Edit block settings</h2>
<form action="{{ path('snippet_settings_block', { 'sequenceNumber' : sequenceNumber }) }}" method="post">

    <textarea class="regular-text" cols="60" rows="4" required="required" name="form[text]" id="form_text"></textarea>

    <br />
     <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="{{ref}}" />
    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <div id="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="update-button" value="Update" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the textarea?

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: What is the contents of `settingsPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textarea that was inserted into the page, was interfering with a script that said all textareas should be disabled.